# Protractor e2e tests using selenium are not running on IE11 | TimeOut issue

Tags: selenium, protractor, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to run protractor e2e tests on IE11. tests are failing with timeout error.

```
[Test Error Output]
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
[19:03:47]
[should not allow Clifton to create a sub-folder inside a folder previously created by Emmett] Failed: JavaScript error in async script. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.29 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: '', ip: '10.50.10.158', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=1, ignoreZoomSetting=false, enablePersistentHover=false, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, ie.enableFullPageScreenshot=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000, ie.forceShellWindowsApi=false, version=11, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, requireWindowFocus=true, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:48570/, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=}]
```

I tried below this as mentioned in different blogs or post /issue links

1. Increase the test case time out from protractor e2e configuration.
2. Updating the protractor and selenium IE driver version.
3. Adding IE specific configuration setting in e2e configuration. e.g

   capabilities: {

   ```
   elementScrollBehavior: 1,
       browserName: 'chrome',
       // IE specific, enables modifier keys (eg. CTRL+CLICK)
       requireWindowFocus: true,
       // If this is set to be true, specs will be sharded by file (i.e. all
       // files to be run by this set of capabilities will run in parallel).
       // Default is false.
       shardTestFiles: false,
       // Maximum number of browser instances that can run in parallel for this
       // set of capabilities. This is only needed if shardTestFiles is true.
       // Default is 1.
       maxInstances: 1,
       loggingPrefs: {
       //this is a chrome specific setting - no effect on other browser runs
       performance: "OFF"
       },
       nativeEvents: false,
       unexpectedAlertBehaviour: 'accept',
       ignoreProtectedModeSettings: true,
       enablePersistentHover: true,
       requireWindowFocus: true,
       ignoreZoomSetting: true,
       INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS: true
       }
   ```

   4. Configuring the IE browser settings as recommended in the below link     http://elgalu.github.io/2014/run-protractor-against-internet-explorer-vm/#

      [Protractor test in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37456099/protractor-test-in-ie?rq=1)
   5. Using browser.driver.get() instead of browser.get() as mentioned in link:    https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4268

Is their any limitations running protractor e2e tests on IE11 ?

Comment: Which timeout value you've changed and can you paste your specs?

Comment: I modified jasmineNodeOpts: {
  defaultTimeoutInterval: 500000
 }
 
 also increased the allScriptsTimeout: 500000 my e2e tests works perfectly on chrome and firefox.