# How to run Protractor specs on IE 11?

Tags: protractor, internet-explorer-11

I have been trying to run protractor specs on IE 11,with following conf.js:

```
 multiCapabilities: [
       {
        'browserName': 'internet explorer',
         version: 11,
         'ignoreProtectedModeSettings': true
       // 'idle-duration':10000,
    }, 
    }],
```

And added this as well:

```
 seleniumArgs: 'C:/Users/LJQAuser/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/IEDriverServer.exe',
```

And set directConnect to : false

But still its showing error:

Error in console is:
[12:38:42] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[12:38:43] E/launcher - Error: Error: Server terminated early with status 1
  at earlyTermination.catch.e (C:\Users\LJQAuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\remote\index.js:252:52)
  at :null:null
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

Closing report
[12:38:43] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100

Answer (score 0):

There is tons of issues with internet explorer. Probably you wont be able to run it successfully.

There is alot of manual steps also to be applied.

Here is some basic guide how to setup:

[Protractor test in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37456099/protractor-test-in-ie)

https://qavalidation.com/2017/11/run-protractor-test-ie-internet-explorer.html/

Good luck!

Comment: After doing all above settings manually, I am still getting this error:                                                
] E/launcher - Error: Error: Server terminated early with status 1

Comment: Can anybody help on this??

Comment: This was resolved when I enabled the protective mode on for all 4 settings in internet options in IE.

Comment: What do you mean with tons of issues Infern0? I'm analyzing using protractor with IE for UI Tests in a real project. Would you recommended just not considering this approach and going directly with backend Selenium for example?