# how to run protractor in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, protractor

I am new to the protractor . I am trying to run my protractor test in IE browser getting "Unable to create new Service :Internet Explorer driverservice". 
Can anyone please help me to run a test in IE with step by Step process.

I am using Protractor version : "^5.4.0". and IE version 11

Answer (score 0):

at this point i was not able to run it due microsoft issues.

but you can try, here are the links with guides:

https://qavalidation.com/2017/11/run-protractor-test-ie-internet-explorer.html

[Protractor test in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37456099/protractor-test-in-ie)

Comment: Where i should i mention IE driver server path in config file?