# Protractor IE11 not compatible with ES6 - producing JavascriptError: Error executing JavaScript

Tags: typescript, protractor, internet-explorer-11

I am using typescript with protractor. All my tests are passing find in Chrome and Firefox but failing in IE11.

Error:

```
  JavascriptError: Error executing JavaScript
 Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
 System info: host: 'INENGHOSHA1L1C', ip: '10.42.47.147', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
 Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "lib": ["dom", "es7"],
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "transform",
    "removeComments": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "mapRoot": "transform",
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],
    "types": ["node", "cucumber"]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "typescript"]
}
```

my IE capability:

```
browserName: 'internet explorer',
    ignoreProtectedModeSettings: true,
    platform: 'ANY',
    version: '11',
    args: ['--silent', '--no-sandbox', '--test-type=browser', '--lang=US', '--start-maximized'],
```

I use to run:

```
tsc
```

to compile TS to JS and then run protractor command to execute tests.

Can you let me know, what I am missing for running my tests successfully against IE11?

Note:

For some of the test, couple of step execute just fine in IE but some features like map function/Expected conditions are failing

Comment: Can your app run well in IE 11 without protractor? Besides, a lot of es6 syntax is not supported by IE 11, you should convert your typescript to es5 javascript. You could try to modify the `target` in **tsconfig.json** to `es5`.

Comment: I have already tried that. but no luck!

Comment: You could try to enable or disable all the protected mode on all 4 zones in IE and make sure the statuses are the same on all zones. You could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37456099/protractor-test-in-ie) for the detailed steps of protractor test in IE. If it still doesn't work, it could be better if you provide [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can have a better understanding of the issue.

Comment: I just discovered that one of the dependency library having es6 code only. I removed the library and it is wotking now.

Comment: So glad that you have solved the issue. You could post an answer as the solution for the issue and mark the answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.